# questions about php and node.js with answers

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, backend

I'm working with PHP and I love this language but when I look at big websites there a small percentage of them using PHP and the rest of using node.js etc, so based on the big websites like Netflix, etc, have some questions

```
1- Is PHP required in companies?
2- what PHP framework should I learn 
3- what frontend framework, etc, good for PHP?
4- is node.js better than PHP
```

if there is anything wrong or you can correct me I'm here to learn :)
I'm very lost I really need the answer I don't know where to go.

Comment: that's opinion-based

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. _"1- when you change variables values in the backend you must refresh the page to load the new values, but with node, you don't have to"_ is wrong. I've worked in projects with PHP backends for Angular single page applications and projects with static Node.js pages with EJS.

Comment: thanks, @jabaa for the answer, so for dynamic pages PHP better ?.
I'm sorry for taking your time.

Comment: There is no better

Comment: thanks, @jabaa for your time and for your explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- in PHP there is no way to automatically refresh the page however
  there is a guide on this [page](https://dev.to/felipperegazio/a-complete-live-reload-feature-for-php-projects-in-a-single-class-380m) to do that
- if you started to use a framework like Laravel you can do that with
  the Browsersync plugin
- I have seen a lot of PHP and Laravel projects requests in freelancing
  websites than node js so yes it's required
- both languages are needed there is no language better than the other
  one each one have its use cases

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me and sorry for wasting your time and for the wrong question at the beginning.